# Date Formatting in R

Tags: r

I have the following dates in a data set (Year/Month)

```
colnames(data)
 [1] "2000/12" "2001/03" "2001/06" "2001/09" "2001/12" "2002/03" "2002/06" "2002/09" "2002/12"
[10] "2003/03" "2003/06" "2003/09" "2003/12" "2004/03" "2004/06" "2004/09" "2004/12" "2005/03"
[19] "2005/06" "2005/09" "2005/12" "2006/03" "2006/06" "2006/09" "2006/12" "2007/03" "2007/06"
[28] "2007/09" "2007/12" "2008/03" "2008/06" "2008/09" "2008/12" "2009/03" "2009/06" "2009/09"
[37] "2009/12" "2010/03" "2010/06" "2010/09" "2010/12" "2011/03" "2011/06" "2011/09" "2011/12"
[46] "2012/03" "2012/06" "2012/09" "2012/12" "2013/03" "2013/06" "2013/09" "2013/12" "2014/03"
[55] "2014/06" "2014/09" "2014/12" "2015/03" "2015/06" "2015/09"
```

I want them formated such that they are no longer strings but numeric dates identified by R. But the command won't work.

```
as.Date(colnames(data),format = "%Y/%m")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[31] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NVM just firgured it out.

Comment: as.Date(as.yearmon(colnames(data),"%Y/%m"))

Comment: Very peculiar that the as.Date function is unable to handle dates without days

Comment: Not peculiar at all. A "date" is not a "month". You should also put in the library() call for the as.yearmon function. (Please learn to search. This is a duplicate of other questions on SO.)

Answer (score 0):

This should also work with XTS

```
library(XTS)
data = strptime(data,format="%Y/%m")
```